# adding Jarray to Jobject C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I use the GetFoldersTree to add new Jarray to a dynamic object  (Jobject). it works fine but just for the first level. I mean with the first level that it adds the property "ListOfSubFolders" just for the first object "rootFolder" not to the generated subfolder.

```
private async Task GetFoldersTree(string projectId, dynamic rootFolder)
{
    List<dynamic> contents = await GetContent(rootFolder);
                              
    List<dynamic> contentsFolder = contents.Where(x => x.type == "folders").ToList();
    if (contentsFolder.Count > 0)
    {
        rootFolder.Add("ListOfSubFolders", JArray.FromObject(contentsFolder));
        foreach (var folder in contentsFolder)
        {
           // recursive call
           await GetFoldersTree(projectId, folder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.anotherdevblog.net/posts/flattening-json-in-json-net

Comment: I suggest you ask yourself what type you *actually* expect `rootFolder` to be. Your use of `dynamic` is effectively avoiding thinking about that type (and various other types) - which means you can't lean on the compiler to help you find mistakes. (In this case, I expect that the mistake is that `JArray.FromObject` is creating *new* elements from `contentsFolder`, but you're then only adding the nested folders into the *original* objects. I would strongly recommend avoiding `dynamic` unless you have a really, really good reason to use it.

Comment: I have to use dynamic because the whole system works with dynamic object. I can follow that the sub folder get the the new contents but when i code come back to the first the rootfolder it delete the update of the sub folder